# VBA Excel - Problems with a simple macro to auto-fill cells for a budgeting spreadsheet I'm attempting to make

Tags: excel, vba, date

**Disclosure: I'm fairly inexperienced at coding of most sorts but have a reasonable understanding of the logic behind it and quite often just need a little push with getting syntax's right etc.**

What I'm trying to do is create a spreadsheet where across the top row is a list of consecutive dates. In the first few columns is data for bills etc. What I want my macro to do is look at the amount of a bill, the start and end dates and the frequency of the bill (weekly/monthly etc) and then populate the cells in that same row in the columns of the dates where the bill is due. I've spent the last day coming up with this code and I was pretty happy with it until I went to run it. I've already got rid of a few bugs where I was using a variable.Value which apparently doesn't exist but now I'm up against some issues outside of my grasp. And I've had no luck searching the internet.

The first problem that the debug finds is on this line:

```
currentDate = Cells(G, currentRow).Value 'Set Start Date
```

I'm getting a Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error. I'm sure that it's just a simple syntax problem or something. What that line is supposed to be doing (*in the first instance*) is looking at the Start Date in Cell "G3" which is formated as a date (04-Feb-14) and assigning the variable currentDate to that date so that I can then do a search across all the dates in the first row for that 'currentDate'.

Am I being clear enough? My code is below.

My Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim currentDate As Date
   Dim currentRow As Integer
   Dim repeatuntilDate As Date
   Dim repeatuntilRow As Integer
   currentRow = 3 'First row of entries
   repeatuntilRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'Last row of entries
   While currentRow < repeatuntilRow 'Loop from first row until last row of entries
   currentDate = Cells(G, currentRow).Value 'Set Start Date
   repeatuntilDate = Cells("H,currentRow").Value 'Set End Date
       While currentDate <= repeatuntilDate 'Loop from Start Date until End Date
       dateAddress = Range("J1:AAI1").Find(currentDate, LookIn:=xlValues).Address 'find the current date within the range of dates in row 1
       Cells("dateAddress.Column,currentRow").Value = Cells("D,currentRow").Value 'Populate cell with amount
       'Increment the currentDate by the chosen frequency
       If Cells("E,currentRow").Value = "Weekly" Then
           currentDate = DateAdd("ww", 1, currentDate)
       ElseIf Cells("E,currentRow").Value = "Fortnightly" Then
           currentDate = DateAdd("ww", 2, currentDate)
       ElseIf Cells("E,currentRow").Value = "Monthly" Then
           currentDate = DateAdd("m", 1, currentDate)
       ElseIf Cells("E,currentRow").Value = "Quarterly" Then
           currentDate = DateAdd("q", 1, currentDatee)
       ElseIf Cells("E,currentRow").Value = "6 Monthly" Then
           currentDate = DateAdd("m", 6, currentDate)
       ElseIf Cells("E,currentRow").Value = "Annually" Then
           currentDate = DateAdd("y", 1, currentDate)
       ' ElseIf Cells("E,currentRow").Value = "Once off" Then
           ' Exit While
       End If
       Wend
   currentRow = currentRow + 1 'Once row is complete, increment to next row down
   Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer why you get `Object Defined Error` you missed the `Cells` property syntax which is:

`Cells(row_index, col_index)` which accepts `long` data type (numbers).

So it should be:

```
currentDate = Cells(currentRow, 7).Value 'G is the 7th column
```

But similarly you can refer to the `col_index` argument like this:

```
currentDate = Cells(currentRow, "G").Value 'take note of the qoutation marks ""
```

Comment: Ah Thank you very much! I should have been able to pick on that one on my own. That let me get further through the code and fix up a few things. I added a `Set` to the dateAddress line but now I am getting a compile error: Object Required on this line:

`Set dateAddress = Range("J1:AAI1").Find(currentDate).Address 'find the current date within the range of dates in row 1`

Any ideas?

Comment: To further clarify that particular line. If I do not include the `Set` at the start, I get a run-time error '91': Object Variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: [HERE](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) is how to use the `.Find` property properly. You use `Set` only if you want to assign `Object` to variable (eg. Set rng = Range("A1") which passes range object to a variable). Range `.Address` property returns a `Value` (which is the address of the range in string format) and not an `Object`. Removing `Set` results to a runtime error because you missed the correct syntax of `.Find` property and the proper way of executing it.

Comment: Once, you've read the article in the link i provided, try to adapt to it, including the proper way of looping. If you get stucked somewhere, raise another question in SO. that way other VBA guru's here can assist you since i'm not always around. :)

Comment: Cool! Thank you a lot! You've been a big help :) I'll see how I go after reading that article.

Comment: That article helped a lot L42. I've since discovered more errors which I'm having difficulties with but I will post it under a new question in SO.

Comment: No problemo, all people in SO are glad to be of helped.